# In birt report table not properly fit into pdf size

Tags: birt, birt-deapi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzHUy.jpg)

how to fit the birt report table not properly fit into pdf size because it showing only few data

Answer (score 0):

**On Format**

You are using the web viewer in your example. If you want a PDF, you need to press the arrow next to the viewer button and choose "View Report as PDF".

[image]

---

**On Size**

Most elements have a `Properties` tab that lets you select width and height relative to the parent element. If you set this to 100%, it will use the full width/height of the parent. However, if single elements have a minimum absolute width - like having lots of columns - the 100% may be forced to be ignored. Then you have to change the single elements first.

[image]

---

**On Orientation**

You might have a fixed set of columns, but it still does not fit the report result. Changing the orientation to landscape can help here - this is especially useful for wide tables. Orientation can be changed in the `Master Page` tab under `Properties -> General -> Orientation`.

[image]